# How to dynamically trigger different back end services based on user input in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Based on the user input from UI (prod, dev, qa), I want to select different backend env and trigger respective backend APIs. I have a home component. From there, I am capturing the user env using a dropdown. Then the data is passed to a service, but I am not able to change the env variable value dynamically.

home component HTML

```
<select #tbchange (change)="OntbChange($event.target.value)">
  <option value="choose">Select</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { SailsService } from './../services/sails.service';
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validator, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

@ViewChild('tbchange') tbchange: ElementRef;

export class HomeComponent  {
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.conn.nativeElement.value);
    if (this.conn.nativeElement.value === 'l2') {
      if (this.myForm.value.uuid.length !== 0) {
        this.uuid = this.myForm.value.uuid;
        // this.testBed = this.myForm.get('testbed').value;
        console.log(this.uuid);
        // console.log(this.testBed);
        this
          .sails
          .getData(this.myForm.value.uuid, this.tbchange.nativeElement.value)
          .then((success) => {
            const user = success.json();
            this.l2UserData = user.userData;
            if (this.l2UserData.length > 0) {
              this.noResponse = false;
              this.isL2Connection = true;
              this.isL3Connection = false;
          } else {
            this.noResponse = true;
          }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.isL2Connection = true;
            this.isL3Connection = false;
            console.log('Error is', error);
          })
      }
    }
}
```

sails.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {LogService} from './log.service';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {ApiService} from './http/api.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export const SERVICE_AUDIENCE = 'a';

@Injectable()
export class SailsService extends ApiService {
  constructor(http: Http,
    log: LogService) {
    if (!environment.services || !environment.services[SERVICE_AUDIENCE]) {
      `enter code here`throw new Error('environment.service for the `enter code here`LabApiService is `enter `enter code here`enter code here`code here`missing');
        }
        super(SERVICE_AUDIENCE, http, log);
      }

  getData(uuid, env) {
    return this
      .get(`/api/connection/xxx?uuid=${uuid}&env=${env}`)
      .toPromise()
  }
```

env.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  debug: {
    apiCalls: '*'
  },
  services: {
    'a': 'http://xxxx:8000',
    'b': 'http://localhost:1337',
    'c': 'xxxxxxx:9000'
  }
};
```

I have an API service where the lower-level URL concatenation and REST methods are written. The problem I am facing is that before the `getData` function is called on user API trigger, the constructor is getting initialized and storing the value of `export const SERVICE_AUDIENCE = 'a';`. Somehow, I have to dynamically change the value of `SERVICE_AUDIENCE` based on the user selection env and trigger a different env string. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So a comment I have is this setup is a bit off.  Typically environments are entirely different versions of the app, and not something a user can just select